# Nativescript gridview in horizontal direction

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to display a large list of items in horizontal direction. I found [GridView](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-grid-view) which uses UICollectionView (for iOS) or RecyclerView (for android) which is working properly in vertical direction. But I cannot find a way to make it horizontal.

I was wonder is there a way to use this component in horizontal direction or is there another component for this purpose?

PS: I don't want to use a normal ScrollView because it does not use lazy loading for items and for large lists, it will destroy performance of the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use [RadListView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/item-layouts) here and set the [scrollDirection](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/listviewlinearlayout.html#scrolldirection) to `Horizontal` on the item layout.

```
npm i --save nativescript-ui-listview
```